# How to remove a specific element when the all button is pressed on Jquery Isotope plugin?

Tags: jquery

Thats the code I am trying to sort. I need the all button to hide the div with class exit and when the button "more than 1265" is clicked to show it again.

```
        <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>

          <meta charset="utf-8" />
          <title>Combination filters &middot; Isotope Demo</title>

          <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

          <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />

          <!-- scripts at bottom of page -->


        </head>
        <body class="demos ">

          <section id="content">

            <h1>Find your topload Tester</h1>
            <h3>Customize your datasheet according to your sample's dimensions</h3>


        <section id="options" class="clearfix combo-filters">




            <div class="option-combo height">
              <h4>Height (mm)</h4>
              <ul class="filter option-set clearfix " data-filter-group="height"> 
                <li><a id="all" href="#filter-height-any" data-filter-value="*" class="selected">All</a>

                  <li><a href="#filter-height-525" data-filter-value=".525">525 or less</a>

                  <li><a href="#filter-height-645" data-filter-value=".645">645 or less</a>

                  <li><a href="#filter-height-1265" data-filter-value=".1265">more than 1265</a>

              </ul>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="option-combo width">
              <h4>Width &nbsp;(mm)</h4>
              <ul class="filter option-set clearfix " data-filter-group="width"> 
                <li><a id="all" href="#filter-width-any" data-filter-value="" class="selected">All</a>

                  <li><a href="#filter-width-134" data-filter-value=".134w">134 or less</a>

                  <li><a href="#filter-width-190" data-filter-value=".190w">190 or less</a>

                  <li><a href="#filter-width-290" data-filter-value=".290w">290 or less</a>

                  <li><a href="#filter-width-328" data-filter-value=".328w">328 or less</a>

                  <li><a href="#filter-width-420" data-filter-value=".420w">420 or more</a>

              </ul>
            </div>
            <br>
          <br>
            <div class="option-combo depth">
              <h4>Depth (mm)</h4>
              <ul class="filter option-set clearfix " data-filter-group="depth"> 
                <li><a id="all" href="#filter-depth-any" data-filter-value="" class="selected">All</a>

                  <li><a href="#filter-depth-134" data-filter-value=".134d">134 or less</a>

                  <li><a href="#filter-depth-190" data-filter-value=".190d">190 or less</a>

                  <li><a href="#filter-depth-290" data-filter-value=".290d">290 or less</a>

                  <li><a href="#filter-depth" data-filter-value=".328d">328 or less</a> 

                  <li><a href="#filter-depth-420" data-filter-value=".420d">420 or more</a>           
              </ul>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>

            <div class="option-combo load">
              <h4>Load (kN)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h4>
              <ul class="filter option-set clearfix " data-filter-group="load"> 
                <li><a id="all" href="#filter-load-any" data-filter-value="" class="selected">All</a>

                  <li><a href="#filter-load-2.5" data-filter-value=".2-5l">2.5 or less</a>

                  <li><a href="#filter-load-5" data-filter-value=".5l">5 or less</a>

                  <li><a href="#filter-load-10" data-filter-value=".10l">10 or less</a>

                  <li><a href="#filter-load-25" data-filter-value=".25l">25 or less</a> 

                  <li><a href="#filter-load-50" data-filter-value=".50l">50 or more</a>           
              </ul>
            </div>


        </section> <!-- #options -->

        <div id="container" class="clearfix">



                <div id="data1" class="width-height-depth 525 134w 290w 290d 134d 2-5l blue">Datasheet1</div>

                <div id="data2" class="width-height-depth 645   190w 328w 328d 190d 5l">Datasheet2</div>

                <div id="data3" class="width-height-depth 50l 25l 10l ">Datasheet3</div>

                <div id="exit" class="width-height-depth 1265">This configuration is beyond the standard range of top-load testers. Please contact Mecmesin Sales to discuss ways to meet your requirements</div>


        </div> <!-- #container -->

        <script src="../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(function(){

            var $container = $('#container'),
                filters = {};

            $container.isotope({
              itemSelector : '.width-height-depth',

              masonry: {
                columnWidth: 80
              },
              filter: '#data1,#data2 , #data3'
            });

            // filter buttons
            $('.filter a').click(function(){
              var $this = $(this);
              // don't proceed if already selected
              if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
                return;
              }

              var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
              // change selected class
              $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
              $this.addClass('selected');

              // store filter value in object
              // i.e. filters.color = 'red'
              var group = $optionSet.attr('data-filter-group');
              filters[ group ] = $this.attr('data-filter-value');
              // convert object into array
              var isoFilters = [];
              for ( var prop in filters ) {
                isoFilters.push( filters[ prop ] )
              }
              var selector = isoFilters.join('');
              $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

              return false;
            });



          });



        </script>


            <footer>
             <p>If you cant find what you are looking for blah blah blah....</p>
            </footer>

          </section> <!-- #content -->


        </body>
        </html>
```

I ve tried your solution. Its almost working but when I repress the "more than 1265" button the text doesnt appear again. It seems that a display:none property is applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean by *remove* is to *hide*, it is pretty simple.

1. First you bind an handler on click of the 'All' button which will hide said element.
2. Then you bind another handler on change of the `select` element. Check if your value is the appropriate one, and then show.

Your code will look like this:

```
  $('button').on('click', function(){

    $('#exit').hide();

  });

  $('select').on('change', function(){

    if( $(this).val() === '{your-appropriate-value}' ) $('#exit').show();

  });
```

<kbd>[**Working demo**](http://jsbin.com/oqafix/1)</kbd>

### Edit

Since you edited your question, I will give you a more specific answer. I will keep my general answer for anybody in the future who might search for something similar.

In order to do what you wish to do, what you have to change in the code above is:

1. Bind the click function to `a#all`.
2. Bind your second function to a click of `.filter a` and then check if appropriate and show. To be honest, this isn't that necessary at all, you could just bind it to your specific element (`#filter-height-1265`) since all your elements have an `id`. I am giving you a more general answer, though, so perhaps if you need to tweak it you get the gist.
3. Also, in this case, you might want the functions to `return false`.

Your code will look like this:

```
  $('a#all').on('click', function(){

    $('#exit').hide();
    return false;

  });

  $('.filter a').on('click', function(){

    if( $(this).data('filter-value') == '.1265' ) $('#exit').show();
    return false;

  });
```

Comment: instead of .val() what can I use for data-filter-value?

Comment: Please be more specific, perhaps by posting your code. To get the `data-filter` value, you could do it using the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method.

Comment: I have edited the question so that you can see the code. Thank you so much for helping me,

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I edited my answer with new code and explaination.